# "Could not load file or assemly" "The specified file could not be found" exception

Tags: c#, wpf, file, exception, .net-assembly

I'm trying to run a C# program on another computer, and since I was experiencing some troubles running the program, I put everything in the "window.initialized" event inside of a Try-statement.

When I then run the program on the other computer, I get an exception saying that "System.Data.SQLite.dll" cannot be found, even though it's sitting right in the debugfolder where the .exe I'm executing also is located. This feels very weird and I have no idea how to solve it.

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: Is the version in the folder the same as the version your application is compiled against?

Comment: debug folder? You mean you are running from visual studio on the other computer?

Comment: @ChrisBint Yes, it is the same version.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I basically zipped my debugfolder (which I got when debugging my program from Visual Studio) and sent it to the other computer.

Comment: Have you enabled fusion logging to see what else it may be loading (and failing)

Comment: @ChrisBint No I have not, I'll try that though and come back with results.

Comment: @ChrisBint Here's what I found http://pastebin.com/a54WbLgF I don't know why this is happening

Comment: @Tokfrans Strange, that looks like it loaded it okay, can you put up the full exception message. Also, what platform are you targetting?

Answer (score 1):

Here are three points which I know to cause this issue:

a) As said in your comments, the assembly reference points to another version than the one of the file in the program directory.

b) The application is targeting a different platform than the assembly (i.e. x86 vs x64). I'm not sure, but it might cause the app to work on one machine and not on the other, when one assembly is built against 'Any CPU' and one against a specific platform (x86 or x64).

c) The referenced assembly is targeting a .NET framework version which is different from the on of the application itself and which is available on the development machine, but not on the other machine. This will cause an assembly binding exception. To check, have a look at the property window after selecting the assembly in question:

[image: Runtime Version]

Not sure whether there are more, but I hope it helps.

Comment: Both my machine and the one I'm testing the program on runs x64, and since it works for me that can't be it. But I'll try to install the NET version which the assembly is using and come back with results.